# my customized fonts and photos in android studio don't work

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I downloaded an image and I created a folder called assets to put the images in and declared it in pubspec and I wrote the location and everything in main.dart but is send me a messages that says unable to load asset. when I tried new android resource directory instead of new directory with the fonts it told me Cannot find resource directory for module Module: 'untitled_android'enter image description here

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NA5z.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

be sure to do pub get

and maybe you forgot / after assets

```
  assets:
     - assets/
```